# WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml

I wrote my first WPF UserControl today, and I would like you to review it.  Its purpose is to have images by default resize with the page, but expand to full size with a double-click:

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyApp.ImageDisplay"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <ScrollViewer Name="Container" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" DoubleTapped="ImageDisplay_DoubleTapped"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" ZoomMode="Disabled">

        <Border Name="ImBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
            <Image Name="ImHolder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        </Border>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

This is my code-behind:

```cs
public sealed partial class ImageDisplay : UserControl
{
    public ImageDisplay()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ImageDisplay_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageDisplay sv = (ImageDisplay)sender;
        if (sv.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility == ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled)
        {
            sv.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
        }
        else
        {
            sv.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
        }
    }

    private ScrollBarVisibility HorizontalScrollBarVisibility
    {
        get { return Container.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility; }
        set { Container.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = value; }
    }

    public ImageSource SetSource
    {
        get { return ImHolder.Source; }
        set { ImHolder.Source = value; }
    }

    public Brush SetBorderColor
    {
        get { return ImBorder.BorderBrush; }
        set { ImBorder.BorderBrush = value; }
    }

    public Thickness SetBorderThickness
    {
        get { return ImBorder.BorderThickness; }
        set { ImBorder.BorderThickness = value; }
    }
}
```

Some places I have read say you should do this so you only set the value if it needs to be changed.:

```cs
public ImageSource SetSource
{
    get { return ImHolder.Source; }
    set
    {
        if (ImHolder.Source == value) { return; }
        ImHolder.Source = value;
    }
}
```

This is what I am trying to replace (the Behaviors class is not shown):

```xml
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" MaxZoomFactor="2" MinZoomFactor="1" MaxWidth="1067">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DoubleTapped">
            <global:ViewboxDoubleTap />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Image Source="MyImage.png"/>
    </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This is what I am replacing it with:

```xml
<Page xmlns:global="using:MyApp" ... >

<global:ImageDisplay SetSource="MyImage.png" MaxWidth="1067" SetBorderThickness="1"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Architecture

From your comment I deduce that you're not actually creating a UserControl here, but deriving from ScrollViewer while having ScrollViewer your root of your XAML.

I don't think this is a good thing: You should derive from ScrollViewer whenever you want to make a custom ScrollViewer. It still should behave as a ScrollViewer then. If your control is used like this:

```
<YourControl />
```

everything will work as expected. But if your control is used like this:

```
<YourControl> <TextBlock /> </YourControl>
```

either your content or the TextBlock will win, depending on when InitializeComponent is called. That's probably not what you want.

Instead, you should either derive from UserControl or implement a CustomControl by deriving from something that really fits the behavior of what you want to achieve (FrameworkElement, Control or something else).

But in WPF, it's usually easier to style or template an existing control. For help making these decisions, please read this at least twice: [MSDN - Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx)

Actually, in your case, you'd most probably want to **derive from Image**. Evidence for that is that you're delegating many properties to your `ImHolder` image. You want to build an image with some additional behavior. That's not a ScrollViewer, it's an image.

You could create a [new style for your control in Generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232333/4317569), set a [custom ControlTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131106/wpf-controltemplate-vs-usercontrol) containing the ScrollViewer and Border, [override the DefaultStyleKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658599/when-overriding-defaultstylekey-is-necessary) and continue from there. Please note that this is advanced stuff.

### Naming

1. Please don't rename stuff if there is no reason to do so: If the thickness of a border is called `BorderThickness` here and `BorderWidth` there, meaning the same thing, this will probably confuse the user of your control.
2. Is there a reason why your properties are prefixed with `Set`? Only methods that set things should be prefixed with `Set`. Properties shouldn't start with verbs, because they don't do things but describe something.

### Performance

Checking if the value has changed before setting it provides **no additional value**, if you're not doing anything that has side effects, e.g. raising property change events or clearing a cache:

```
// Good:
public string Value
{
    get { return this.value; }
    set { this.borderWidth = value; }
}

// Even better:
public string Value { get; set; }

// Not so good:
public string Value
{
    get { return this.value; }
    set 
    { 
        if (this.borderWidth == value) return;
        this.borderWidth = value; 
    }
}

// Good:
public string Value
{
    get { return this.value; }
    set 
    { 
        if (this.borderWidth == value) return;
        this.borderWidth = value; 
        this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.Value);
    }
}
```

I would always prefer easier code over "optimized" code, if there is no evident performance problem. ReSharper will even tell you that this is a "Redundant check before assignment".

Furthermore, you're doing **delegation** here: You're not implementing the property yourself, but forwarding its setter and getter to the Image instance. Optimizations will be done there by the dependency property system itself:

```
// Good:
public string Value
{
    get { return this.otherObject.Value; }
    get { this.otherObject.Value = value; }
}
```

Comment: "Inner" would be preferable to "My" @Hosch250.

Comment: See updated answer :)

Comment: Can you include your complete XAML? I don't see what your control... does.

Comment: Composing new behavior by using existing things and adding triggers/actions/behaviors as you did in the original StackOverflow answer is the best solution, actually. I wouldn't create a control for this, if the existing solution works.

Answer (score 1):

UserControl vs Custom Control

*UserControl* - I use these for top-level controls that are not commonly re-used and aren't customized. The reason for that is because they are very hard to get\set values on sub-controls and are very difficult to unit test. I would suggest never using code behind for user controls for that reason.

*Custom Controls (templated controls)* - These are wonderful for customizations on groups of controls, however they don't have very good designer support (which is why i do all my designing in the XAML\XML editor). Personally, I use custom controls for 90% of my UI and only use UserControls for arranging the custom controls & binding them to their view models (see [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) for more info on view models).

In your case, I personally would've used a custom control...